# Why 'fputc' use an INT as its parameter instead of CHAR?

Tags: function

standard C lib:

```
int fputc(int c , FILE *stream);
```

And such behaviors occured many times, e.g:

```
    int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
    int putchar(int c);
```

why not use CHAR as it really is?
If use INT is necessary, when should I use INT instead of CHAR?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most *likely* (in my opinion, since much of the rationale behind early C is lost in the depths of time), it it was simply to mirror the types used in the `fgetc` type functions which must be able to return any real character *plus* the `EOF` special character. The `fgetc` function gets the next character converted to an `int`, and uses a special marker value `EOF` to indicate the end of the stream.

To do that, they needed the wider `int` type since a `char` isn't quite large enough to hold all possible characters *plus one more thing.*

And, since the developers of C seemed to prefer a rather *minimalist* approach to code, it makes sense that they would use the same type, to allow for code such as:

```
filecopy(ifp, ofp)
    FILE *ifp;
    FILE *ofp;
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc (ifp)) != EOF)
        fputc (c, ofp);
}
```

Comment: But we won't write EOF to an FILE whenever...
So you said 'simply mirror' ,am I right?^_^

Comment: So what is the behaviour of `putchar(-1)` ?

Comment: No, you don't write EOF but, in a simple stdin/stdout filter program, it's easier just to use the one (int) variable rather than to try and coerce types.

Comment: @Neil, the standard says it's converted to an unsigned char.

Comment: Get it^_^ further more, must I use INT instead of CHAR to be an function parameter as a trick from now on?

Comment: This might be a factor but I think there is a more fundamental reason. See *No char parameters...*.

Comment: If `EOF` is passed into `fgetc()` as well as any non-`unsigned char`, a character is still printed.  If mirroring `fgetc()`, with `EOF`, certainly nothing would get printed.  So IMO, this is a guess(reasonable)  and not the right reason for an `int` parameter.

Comment: @paxdiablo Good explanation but still i have doubt on the fact that fputs convert argument int as unsigned char so how can one lay on  this  statement " they needed the wider int type since a char isn't quite large enough to hold all possible characters plus one more thing "  and why don't my compiler through warring or error when unsigned char is used instead int ?

Comment: @pravu, if you want a function to be able to give you ALL possible characters PLUS one other value, a character isn't enough for the return value. The sentinal value EOF cannot use one of the characters for its encoding since you couldn't then tell the difference between end of stream and a real character with that value. That's why fgetc returns int rather than char.

Comment: If you have doubts about it taking an int and treating it as unsigned char, read the standard, that's _exactly_ what it says :-) and the reason passing a char is not an issue is because of the allowable conversions that C does for you.

Answer (score 6):

#### No char parameters in K&R C

One reason is that in early versions<sup>1</sup> of C there were no `char` parameters.

Yes, you could declare a parameter as `char` or `float` but it was considered `int` or `double`. Therefore, it would have, then, been somewhat misleading to document an interface as taking a `char` argument.

I believe this is still true today for functions declared without prototypes, in order for it to be possible to interoperate with older code.

---

<sup>1. Early, but still widespread. C was a quick success and became the first (and still, mostly, *the only*) widely successful systems programming language.</sup>