# why fputc function has integer as argument instead of unsigned char?

Tags: c, file

why fputc function has integer as argument instead of unsigned char? This question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943736/why-fputc-use-an-int-as-its-parameter-instead-of-char) it is mentioned as "int is taken as argument because unsigned char is not large enough" but my point here is even fputc function implicitly convert int to unsigned char isn't it?

**Questions:**

1.Why the argument of fputc is int not unsigned char though fputc convert int back to unsigned char ?

2.No warring nor error when int is replaced with unsigned char?

3.Please can some one give a example where compiler give warring or error when char is used as argument instead of int?

Comment: If you wonder about the implicit conversion: read about [integer promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2)

Comment: @Olaf please don't mark it as duplicate because i had admire it and thought it  need to added some more valid reason

Comment: @Olaf i don't understand you guys why u all  do this without reading complete.Just looking at the reputation if no just blow off really worst experience with this ppl

Comment: Sorry, but your question as asked in the title is a duplicate of the one given in the close-reason. And the text is a dup of other questions - just search, or have a look at the link to the standard I provided already. Please add some thoughts on your onw to asemble the whole picture (and I bet this also has been done on SO already)..